# What is the fallacy in my reasoning of this sentence-to-first-order-logic-problem?

Tags: first-order-logic

Given predicates

- Occupation(p,o) (Person p has job o)
- Client(p1, p2) (Person p1 is a client of person p2)

And constants:

•   Occupations: Lawyer, doctor, officer

•   Persons: Emily, Joe

And sentence:

- There exists a lawyer of which all its clients are doctors.

I then translated the above sentence in first-order logic and came up with this:

∃x[Occupation(x,lawyer) ⟶ ∀y[Occupation(y,doctor) ∧ Client(y,x)]]

This reads (according to me): There exists an X such that if X is a lawyer, then all Y's are a customer of X and they're doctors.

However, peeking at the answers, I found that the only solution was:

∃x[Occupation(x,lawyer) ∧ ∀y[Client(y,x) ⟶ Occupation(y, doctor)]]

This reads (according to me): There exists an X such that if X is a lawyer and all Y's are a client of X, then they are all doctors. I feel like this doesn't express the sentence correctly.

I'm stumped as to why my answer is incorrect! I can't figure out the logical difference between those two sentences and English isn't my main language (so maybe that's where the problem lies?). What is the fallacy in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your translation of your sentence, but this does not correspond to the initial plain English sentence.

This is how I would translate your sentence:

> There exists X such that if X is a lawyer then for every Y, Y is  doctor and a client of X

Pretty much the same as you translated it. What does this mean though? First of all notice that after `there exist X` we have an **if**. This means that the sentence is trivially true (since X can be not a lawyer, and the sentence is still true). So you want to start with a statement that X **is** a lawyer and then add more conditions. Furthermore, let's assume we have X being a lawyer, what does the rest of the sentence mean? It means that there is a lawyer that has **all** people as clients (including themselves) and **all** people are doctors. So if there are 10 people in our universe, then one is a lawyer and all are doctors and clients of his/hers. The initial plain English statement of course just meant that, for example, one lawyer just has 2 clients and both of them are doctors.

Furthermore you are not correct in your translation of the book sentence. Here's my translation:

> There exist X such that X is a lawyer and for every Y, if Y is a client of X, then Y is a doctor.

This is the same as the initial plain English statement. See how it makes the definite statement that X **is** a lawyer and then continues with the conditional.

Comment: A well-structured and concise explanation of the fallacy in my reasoning! Much appreciated!

Comment: "It means that there is a lawyer that has all other people as clients and all other people are doctors." - Not quite; it says that the lawyer is also a doctor, and is among their own clients.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine yes, I took it as Y being different than X, which is sometimes implied in similar formulations. If we want to be strict this should have been explicitly stated in the sentence. Otherwise it means what you said.

Comment: I now understand this too. However, does that statement also hold for the solution I mentioned? (So not the one I came up with)

Comment: @Zimano I am not sure what you mean. Malice's comment does not change the essence of my answer. Are you asking what are the implications of potentially X=Y to the solution? The solution is exactly the same. It just means that **if** X is a client of himself then apart from being a lawyer he has to be a doctor too.

Comment: My apologies. I meant that for the correct solution I mentioned in my question (not the solution I thought of myself) does that solution imply that it is possible that the lawyer is also a doctor and among his own clients? (Since there is no indication that X and Y are distinct)

Comment: @Zimano yes it is possible, but this does not change the answer/solution. The solution is not affected by restricting or not X=Y.

Comment: I edited my answer to follow Malice's comment. Let me know if this confuses matters needlessly. I think it's ok.